# files with same names but in different directories get deleted together- there is no link

Tags: filesystems

files with same names but in different named directories get deleted together when I try to delete one of the directories - I never made a link between these files, there is no link, and they were copied separately at different times. Is there any suggestions as to what it could be doing?

I ended up deleting them both because I had a backup but would still accept any suggestions in case it happens again.

The subdirectories "beans" is what contain the same files but like I said they were not linked so I am not sure why I could not delete one without the other.

A/beans/files

B/beans/files

Comment: How are you deleting the directories?

Comment: By doing rm -r A   and then rm -r beans inside of directory A

Comment: That doesn't really make sense to me. How can you `cd A` if it's gone? Please edit your question, and paste the precise commands (including `cd`) that you used, and any output, if present.

Comment: just to be sure; you say there was no "link", but perhaps you were looking for symlinks? Could there have been hard links?

Comment: @JeffSchaller But even if they were hard links, `rm`-ing one shouldn't delete the other, would it?

Comment: @Sparhawk good point!

Comment: Is it possible that the directories are symlinks? For example `A/beans` is a symlink to `../B/beans`? Try `ls -li` on the files on both directories, that will show the inode number of each file, if inode numbers match then they're pointing at the same inode (but they could still be hardlinks.) Try also `ls -lid A/beans/ B/beans/` to see if the directories have the same inode (and therefore are the same)...